# TFS 2010 Iteration backlog - Burndown. Not updating

Tags: iteration, backlog

In my Iteration Backlog generated by TFS 2010, Burn-down chart is not updating with data.It is always showing the below error message.I have "\Iteration 1" in my team project.

The iteration path '\Iteration 1' is not in the cube. Try again after you have a work item with this iteration path and the cube has been processed.

Please help.
Aneesh

Comment: Do you also have a work item assigned to Iteration 1? Please give some more diagnosic information to help you further.